# Z notation specification to modify content of a set

Tags: formal-methods, z-notation

Let's say I have a set:

```
S: Id X Counter

Id: \nat

Counter: \nat
```

Need help to define an operation `filter` which takes in two parameters, `x:\nat` and `y:\nat` which I can apply to `S`. This function will match on the first parameter with `\exists a \in S @ first(a) = x` and then reduce `second(a)` with `y`. If the value is less than or equal to zero, `a` should be removed from the set `S`, otherwise `(first(a), second(a) - y)` should replace `a`.

If the above is indecipherable, just please give me any example definition that operates over a set and modifies it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your set of pairs S of natural numbers is a Z relation between natural
numbers.  Let's give the set of all such relations a name:

```
natrel == ℕ ↔ ℕ
```

Since the filter function will only modify some part of S, it is
convenient to describe that separately.

The modify operation produces for a given pair (x, y) of arguments and a
relation S the set of maplets a ↦ b − y satisfying your description:

- The maplet a ↦ b with a = x is in S and
- the new value b − y is greater than zero.

As a Z "axiomatic description" it is:

```
│   
│   modify : (ℕ × ℕ) → (natrel → natrel)
│   
├───
│   
│   ∀ x, y : ℕ; S : natrel ⦁ 
│     modify (x, y) S =
│       { a, b : ℕ | a ↦ b ∈ S ∧ a = x ∧ b > y ⦁ a ↦ b − y }
│
```

Note that modify (x, y) S may well be empty if there are no such maplets
in S.

Deletion of a maplet a ↦ b ∈ S where b is too small is modeled simply
by excluding it in the set comprehension.

Now the filter operation is easy to define:

```
│   
│   filter : (ℕ × ℕ) → (natrel → natrel)
│   
├───
│   
│   ∀ x, y : ℕ; S : natrel ⦁ 
│     (filter (x, y) S) = ({x} ⩤ S) ∪ (modify (x, y) S)
│
```

So the result of filter (x, y) S is a set union of the unchanged part of
S on the left hand side with the maplets given by modify (x, y) S on the
right hand side:

- Pairs in S where the first element is not x are left unchanged and
- pairs in S where the first element is x are modified (replaced or
  deleted).